# making Order in Paypal Parallel Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

I am trying to place Order with Parallel Paypal Express Checkout. Here is the API [implementation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/making-order-in-paypal-parallel-express-checkout).

I am using `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => Order` in `SetExpressCheckout` and in `DoExpressChecoutPayment` and it gives error (this is required).

When I use  `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => Order` in `SetExpressCheckout` and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => Sale` in `DoExpressChecoutPayment` it works.

All goes well until `DoExpressChecoutPayment`. Please check this

```
DoExpressCheckoutPayment    Request
(
[TOKEN] => EC-4U931568VK402050F
[PAYERID] => BFSU67Z2LX5FJ
[VERSION] => 97.0
[METHOD] => DoExpressCheckoutPayment
[USER] => 'user'
[PWD] => 'pwd'
[SIGNATURE] => 'sig'
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => ORDER
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 200.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => vendortwo2@yhaoo.com
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID] => 25935
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION] => ORDER
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT] => 22.00
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => vendorone@yahoo.com
[PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID] => 25934
)
```

and response from this is:

```
(
[TOKEN] => EC-4U931568VK402050F
[SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
[TIMESTAMP] => 2013-09-26T10:08:27Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 2381c85a926e3
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 97.0
[BUILD] => 7882219
[INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
[SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Failed
[PAYMENTINFO_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => vendortwo2@yhaoo.com
[PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => DRM9QQUAG9UNC
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID] => 25935
[PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 10001
[PAYMENTINFO_0_SHORTMESSAGE] => Internal Error
[PAYMENTINFO_0_LONGMESSAGE] => Internal Error
[PAYMENTINFO_0_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
[PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Failure
[PAYMENTINFO_1_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Failed
[PAYMENTINFO_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => vendorone@yahoo.com
[PAYMENTINFO_1_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => M7HT95CA3PUCE
[PAYMENTINFO_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID] => 25934
[PAYMENTINFO_1_ERRORCODE] => 10001
[PAYMENTINFO_1_SHORTMESSAGE] => Internal Error
[PAYMENTINFO_1_LONGMESSAGE] => Internal Error
[PAYMENTINFO_1_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
[PAYMENTINFO_1_ACK] => Failure
)
```

I have asked same question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/making-order-in-paypal-parallel-express-checkout).

Comment: basically i just want to make Order, therefore in SetExpressCheckout i used PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => Order and PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION => Order. Now in DoExpressCheckoutPayment, if i use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => Sale and PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION => Sale, it works all fine. But i need to place "Order" and therefore need to use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION => Order and PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION => Order in DoExpressCheckoutPayment, that is giving "Internal Error". Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Internal error came because wrong type of account ids are assigned to PAYMENTINFO_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID and PAYMENTINFO_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID in DoExpressCheckoutPayment request. Accounts assigned are personal, they should be paypal Business Accounts instead. that was the reason of "Internal Error". Thanks